# Unable to generate friendly_id from gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm trying to use [Friendly ID](http://norman.github.com/friendly_id/) to handle slugs in my Rails app. When I run "rails generate friendly_id", I get the following error:

/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-3.0.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:239:in `require': no such file to load -- babosa (LoadError)

However, the babosa gem is definitely installed.

How can I even begin to solve this?

Answer (score 3):

I was able to fix the problem by installing Bundler and adding the following lines to "Gemfile" in the root of my app:

> gem 'babosa'
>
> gem 'friendly_id'

Comment: You only need to specify `gem 'friendly_id`'  there, as the gem as a runtime dependency of the babosa gem, so it will be automatically included.

Answer (score 0):

I've not seen this problem myself, but have you tried the Google Group for the gem? It looks like that's the author's preferred communication method, and he looks to be fairly responsive there.

http://groups.google.com/group/friendly_id